# Configuring Website - SQL Server - SUSER_NAME()

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

Haven't done enough web development, and have searched a bit here, and have not found an answer yet.

I wanted to find out how to configure my website/`web.config` to allow me to use `SUSER_NAME()` on my audit triggers in Microsoft SQL Server.

Currently we are connecting to our database with a service account, but other users are authenticating and accessing the web site. When a record is changed, we want to capture the user that made the change, and not the service account used to log into the database.

The App Pool is configured to the service account and the web site is configured using Windows authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation (but this keeps getting turned off somehow).

The `web.config` has

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

and Windows authentication.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say that the website is configured to use Windows Authentication, do you mean that each users' Windows login is authenticated or that the service account's login is used?

Comment: each user is authenticated, and we validate they are a network user and should have access before advancing in the application.   The connection string though uses integrated security with a specific NT ID as the app pool user.  Currently when a change is made, the SUSER_NAME() pushed to the audit table is the same as the app pool id.  And we want to use the NT ID of the user logged into the database.

Comment: Does this apply to your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417631/how-can-i-log-user-name-when-sql-server-database-on-different-server-than-web-se

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no that doesnt answer it.  The web sites app pool needs to run as a specific user that will have access to the database.  All of the users accessing the web site WILL NOT have access to the database directly.

Comment: If he users don't actually have logins in the database then I believe that the only solution at that point is to have your own homegrown tracking of who the user is on each connection. I'm a database guy, not a web guy though, so it's possible that there's some method that I don't know about.